# Could cash cow be used for a person?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

Could the word cash cow be used for a person? Like a person who is making a lot of money for someone else and probably for himself too?

Comment: Yes. There are plenty of written instances of [see him as a cash cow](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22see+him+as+a+cash+cow%22) in Google Books. But I'm not sure *probably [making a lot of money] for himself too* is justified there - at least *part* of the point of using such a "dehumanising" metaphoric reference is to "objectify" the person being referred to. Nobody really cares if he gets rich as well as the people who are "milking" him (but if they thought that *was* happening, perhaps they'd draw more "milk" rather than let it go to waste on him! :).

Comment: ...when we *bring out the fatted calf* for a celebratory meal, no-one thinks about what a good life that calf had, living off the fat of the land until being turned into top-class dinner. Unlike [kobe beef](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Kobe%20beef), which I understand comes from cows not only *fed* well - they're entertained by soothing classical music (I'm told the best kobe beef comes from cows reared on Mozart & Beethoven! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - and massaged by nubile young ladies, I read in a James Bond novel, or was that a fantasy of Ian Fleming's?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I think the "massaged by nubile young ladies" kobe beef is only available to "gold star" customers of [Fortnum & Mason](https://www.fortnumandmason.com/). (A bit out of my price bracket, I'm afraid! :)

Answer (score 0):

A "cash cow" is typically a product or a service that brings in a lot of revenue. In my experience, the implication is that the profit is also very high because there's virtually no incremental cost of making a sale.

For example, information products are cash cows for many companies because once you acquire the data, you can sell it over and over again to different people, or bundle it differently and sell it to the same people, for little to no incremental cost. Once you've recovered your investment, every sale is almost entirely profit.

If you were going to refer to a person as a cash cow, it would probably be in the context of someone who bills a relatively high hourly rate to clients. For example, a young associate attorney in a law firm who is working 80 hours a week and billing all his time to clients at $250 an hour might be a cash cow. He's generating a lot of profitable revenue for the law firm (although it's probably not sustainable in the long term).

Comment: So is the employee who is working here is the cash cow or the client with whom he is working

Comment: The employee is the cash cow because s/he is the one generating the revenue.

Comment: Assuming the employee is working on cases for more than one client, the employee would be the cash cow. I suppose if the employee only worked on a single client, you might call the client a cash cow, but that would likely be derogatory.

Comment: I'm still perplexed by people who downvote an answer, yet don't provide their own presumably "correct" answer.

Comment: @swmcdonnell So am I. But I've upvoted you for making some interesting points. I spent most of my career in the accountancy professiuon, and can confirm that "cash cow" is a loosely used term and gets applied to different contexts. I think it originated to describe the type of business that was nearing the end of its life - eg. perhaps its technology was being superseded - so while no further investments were being made in it - it was kept alive as a continuing cash generator until the milk ran dry.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard it used for a person financing his lazy siblings.